# Automatic next lot number in excel log

Tags: excel, function

We are setting up a new way of logging our lot number and I was trying to find a way of doing it without having to manually enter each number.
The number is formatted as `161201-1 "1612"` is the date code, "01" is the sub lot, "-1" is the line.
I want to make it so I only have to enter the first instance then can use a function that will add a line each time.
However there are only 4 lines per sub lot so each time the line reaches "-4" the next sub lot should be higher than the previous.
For example `161201-4` would be followed by `161202-1` (the date code stays constant until I type in a new lot).

I can't figure out what I would do for this kind of function.

Comment: Take a look at [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Put every element of lot number in separate columns and than put it back together with "CONCATENATE" function. I did a sample for you and left the formulas as text in the last row.

[image]